# Conditionally excluding a block of html in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

This is just a simple question: how do I exclude a piece of html on an aspx web form from being returned by the server, based on a server-side evaluation?

I'm not talking about a control specifically since they tend to have Visible parameters, but rather just some raw html.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<div id="divYourDiv" runat="server">
    your stuff goes here...
</div>

//Server side code...
public void ShowYourDiv(bool visible)
{
    this.divYourDiv.Visible = visible;
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to access divYourDiv from the codebehind. Is there something I need to do first to make this accessible?

Comment: make sure you set runat="server"

Answer (score 84):

Some people object to the following method but its one that no one has answered with and I feel that it should be shown as an option. It can be handy when used properly.

```
<% if (ShowLabel) {%>
<label>This will not be shown if the ShowLabel property evaluates false</label>
<%}%>
```

To make this work you would have a public or protected property on your page called ShowLabel which returns a boolean.

Comment: Cool I kind of like that actually. I guess some ppl don't like to mix code and markup, but I'm a coder at heart so this makes more sense to me. :)

Comment: In some cases this is even the only possible solution. For example if you want to conditionally hide <script> tags, which is not possible when you use `runat="server"` with an `ID` to set it's visibilty to false in the code-behind file.

Comment: Note you could define the variable in the markup if you don't want to have to recompile when you change it: <% bool ShowLabel = true; %>.

Comment: Simple and elegant way. This even worked for me when setting visible to false for the same server control in codebehind was not working for some reason.

Comment: yes, had to resort to this because I couldn't add an ID attribute as the generated html was replicated on the client and would result in duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 12):

Put a `PlaceHolder` control around the code. It doesn't render any code for itself (like a `Panel` for example), so it doesn't interfer with the html code when it's visible.

If you set the `Visible` property of the `PlaceHolder` to false, the code inside the `PlaceHolder` will not be rendered to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Through it/set it in a hidden div or panel (if using div, mark runat=server, both render as div). Then make the div/panel visible or keep it hidden depending on your evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap your html inside an asp panel, and set the visible attribute of the panel on the server-side.

Otherwise, Html is client side, you need use javascript to manipulate.  You may be able to render some javascript inside your server-side code, but that normally is not a good idea.